# JS error on ActiveAdmin batch delete action

Tags: activeadmin

I've just installed ActiveAdmin (1.1.0) in one of my projects and already had a Devise user so I went with that.

So far I've added the User and one more model to AA and the delete batch action doesn't work in either.

I've gotten an error on the console upon hitting the action.

#### Expected behavior

Batch delete selected models

#### Actual behavior

Nothing visible, JS error in console.

```
dialog.self.js?body=1:371 Uncaught TypeError: this._addClass is not a function
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWrapper (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/dialog.self.js?body=1:371:8)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWrapper (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self.js?body=1:116:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._super (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self.js?body=1:103:36)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWrapper (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/dialog.self.js?body=1:938:9)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWrapper (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self.js?body=1:116:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/dialog.self.js?body=1:151:8)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self.js?body=1:116:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWidget (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self.js?body=1:286:8)
    at new $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self.js?body=1:77:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self.js?body=1:232:30)
```

I do have `#= require active_admin/base` in active_admin.js.coffee and no other JS has been added to active admin via initializer.

Comment: Which version? 1.1? GitHub master?

Comment: @PiersC activeadmin (1.1.0), edited question to add version. thx

Answer (score 0):

Because of the newest `activeadmin` gem use `jquery3`. You should add `jquery-migrate.js`.
And in my case, I didn't see `/jquery-ui` folder in chrome's Source

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-migrate-3.0.1
```

to your `active_admin.js` file.